# unexpected java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when calling DriverManager.getConnection()

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am writing a Java application which needs to insert some data to MySQL database through JDBC. Here's the related code:

```
public JDBCDecoder() {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Loaded MySQL JDBC driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception attempting to load MySQL JDBC driver");
    }

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("user", "root");
    props.put("password", "root");

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Throwables.propagate(e);
    }
    ....

}
```

Here's the error stack trace that I got after trying to run the code:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getCallerClass(DriverManager.java:477)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:576)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
    at exportclient.JDBCExportClient$JDBCDecoder.<init>(JDBCExportClient.java:179)
    at exportclient.JDBCExportClient.constructExportDecoder(JDBCExportClient.java:604)
    at export.processors.GuestProcessor$1.run(GuestProcessor.java:113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at utils.CoreUtils$1$1.run(CoreUtils.java:259)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

which seems weird to me because: 1) I am not trying to connect to Oracle database; 2) actually I do have an ojdbc6.jar (which contains oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver) in my classpath. So I am completely clueless why this error would happen.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There should be a root cause for this...  Can you please post the full stacktrace ?

Comment: Can you post also the code for your class ?  I assume it is not complete because your `Class.forName(..) }  is not wrapped on a `try/catch` block

Comment: @CristianMeneses Updated (I suppose the code after DriverManager.getConnection() cannot be the cause of this problem?) Thanks!

Comment: `Could not initialize class ....` is an error thrown if the JVM attempts to load a class it has already failed to load.  By the time you see your error, something somewhere else must already have tried and failed to load the Oracle JDBC driver.  Are there any exceptions that get thrown before you see the one you've posted above?

Answer (score 0):

See if this has something to do with your problem: ["As part of its initialization, the DriverManager class will attempt to load the driver classes referenced in the "jdbc.drivers" system property."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried to print out the "jdbc.drivers" system property before calling DriverManager.connections() while the output is "null"......

Comment: It will also attempt to load the drivers listed in all the `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` files found in the classpath